# What are the width and height returned by onSurfaceChanged?

Tags: android

I wonder to what correspond the width and height returned by the following delegate method:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
}
```

On my Samsung S8, it returns the following values:

```
02-20 11:36:42.790 D/GLSurfaceRenderer: onSurfaceChanged
02-20 11:36:42.790 D/MyApp: onSurfaceChanged viewWidth 1080
02-20 11:36:42.790 D/MyApp: onSurfaceChanged viewHeight 2004
02-20 11:36:43.140 D/GLSurfaceRenderer: onSurfaceChanged
02-20 11:36:43.141 D/MyApp: onSurfaceChanged viewWidth 1080
02-20 11:36:43.141 D/MyApp: onSurfaceChanged viewHeight 2076
```

I don't understand to what it corresponds.

Comment: View width and view height? Also this function has nothing to do with OpenGL.

Comment: The 2 sizes are possibly for example when your app runs and the navigation bar is removed when it goes full screen. The surface changed will be called again when that happens. Just like when you rotate the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the purpose of onSurfaceChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523386/what-is-the-purpose-of-onsurfacechanged)